# Number of rows by Group ID conditional

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  ID S1 C
1 1  2  3  
2 1  2  3
3 3  1  1
4 6  2  5
5 6  7  5
```

What I need is the number of rows per group `ID` where `S1 <= C`. This is the desired output.

```
  ID  Obs 
1 1   2 
2 3   1 
3 6   1
```

Even though the question was answered below, I have a follow up question: Is it possible to do the same for multiple columns (S1, S2, ..). For example for the dataframe below:

```
  ID S1  S2 C
1 1  2   2  3  
2 1  2   2  3
3 3  1   1  1
4 6  2   2  5
5 6  7   7  5
```

And then get:

```
  ID  S1.Obs S2.Obs 
1 1   2      2
2 3   1      1
3 6   1      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `base` R solution with `aggregate()`.

```
aggregate(Obs ~ ID, transform(df, Obs = S1 <= C), sum)

#   ID Obs
# 1  1   2
# 2  3   1
# 3  6   1
```

---

A `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(S1 <= C) %>%
  count(ID, name = "Obs")

#   ID Obs
# 1  1   2
# 2  3   1
# 3  6   1
```

---

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 6L), S1 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 7L),
C = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

---

***Extension***

If you want to apply this rule on multiple columns such as S1, S2, S3:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("S"), ~ sum(.x <= C)))
```

Comment: Is this framework possible if I want to test this for multiple column such as S1, S2, S3 and so on, against C.

Answer (score 1):

```
data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 3, 6, 6),
  S1 = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 7),
  C = c(3, 3, 1, 5, 5)
)

library(dplyr)

data.filtered <- data[data$S1 <= data$C,]

data.filtered %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(Obs = length(ID))
```

Comment: With your idea, a  `dplyr` style solution might be `data %>% filter(S1 <= C) %>%  group_by(ID) %>% summarize(Obs = length(ID))`

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[S1 <=C, .(Obs = .N), ID]
#   ID Obs
#1:  1   2
#2:  3   1
#3:  6   1
```

#### data

```
df <-  structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 6L), S1 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 7L),
C = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```